# NullPointerException while counting the number of rows using COUNT() in SQLite helper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting NullPointerException whle performing COUNT() in SQLite. please see the following code -

```
public int getrcofpersons() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    int values = 0;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        myDB=this.openDataBase();
        Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("select count(PersonID) from Persons;",null);
        if (c != null ) {
            String h = "";
            c.moveToFirst();

            count = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PersonID"));

            // put your code to get data from cursor                      

        }

        if(c != null) {
            c.close();
            myDB.close();
        }
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " is the rowcount of persons.");
    return count;

}
```

This function is returning Null value. Even `System.out.println(count + " is the rowcount of persons.");` also showing the `count` value as 0, which is the initialized value. Now I cannot post the logcat, because this code snippet is associated with many other functionalities, that you might not understand. So, please, tell me if I did any mistake in this code.

Please see the following code. This code is calling the above method(which is in the helper.java). 
adapter.java :

```
public int getrowcountofpersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int rc = 0;
        try {

            //open();

            rc = mDbHelper.getrcofpersons(); //Here the nullPointerException is raised.


        //  close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {Log.v("getrowcountofpersons()","5");
            Log.v("Error in getrowcountofpersons() of adapter : ",e.toString());
        }
        Log.v("getrowcountofpersons()","6");
        System.out.println(rc + " is the rowcount of persons in adapter.");
        return rc;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace ?

Comment: Thank you for replying @Veera, I am sorry that I cannot post the stacktrace. But, purely it is a null pointer exception. It did not show, which line of this code is raising that exception. But it is true that, this function is returning null value. I am unable to understand where the `count` variable is becoming null??

Comment: " It did not show, which line of this code is raising that exception." Why not? Usually a stack trace shows exactly that.

Comment: Actually, I am calling this function from an another class. There it is showing that this function is returning null value. But no word about which line in this function is raising it.

Comment: null for primitive? How this is possible that if returntype of a function is int, that returns null? I don't know Java does this.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar, please see the updated code to see which method is calling the already posted method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
count = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PersonID"));
```

to

```
count = c.getInt(0);
```

*There is no column name `PersonID` into your Cursor object c. And this will have only one column so you can retrieve that column using 0 (ZERO) index.*

---

After code update :-

Check if `mDbHelper` is `null` or not. This might be null. So check if you are initiating the `mDbHelper` object.

Comment: That's it most likely, because the column is not called "PersonId" (it should be called something "count")

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pankaj Kumar, I have tried this `count = c.getInt(0);`. But there is no change in the output.

Comment: @nki  If the given code "As it is" then my answer must work. But if there is any change into your code we would like to see that... without code we can't tell the reason

Comment: @nki check if `mDbHelper` is not null. I am sure that `mDbHelper` is null.

Comment: No @Pankaj Kumar, it is not null. Because, I am using the same variable to retrieve other data from the same database, and those functions are working well.

Comment: I agree you are doing right thing, but you should at least check once using if. like  `if (mDbHelper == null) // PRINT THIS IS NULL` into that method

Comment: I have checked it, @PankajKumar. I got to know that it is not null.

Comment: :( . So for NPE the next and only one left suspect is `myDB=this.openDataBase()`. You can check if `myDB` is null after this line and before `Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("select count(PersonID) from Persons;",null);`.

Comment: yes @ Pankaj Kumar, mDbHelper is null there, previously, because of some other error, my code was unable to find this error.